# Recommended way to include bootstrap library in Ember.JS ember-cli App

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I am trying to install properly Twitter Bootstrap in my current ember-cli project.
I did install bootstrap with bower :

```
bower install --save bootstrap
```

Now the library is downloded in */vendor/bootstrap/dist/(css|js|fonts)*
I tried what is mentioned here : http://ember-cli.com/#managing-dependencies
replacing path and css files names but I get errors regarding the *Brocfile.js* file. I think the brocfile format has changed too much compared to the example.

I also tried to @import  with the */app/styles/app.css* file after moving the stylesheets in the /app/styles/ directory :

```
@import url('/assets/bootstrap.css');
@import url('/assets/bootstrap-theme.css');
```

But it did not work. The files are visible true dev server : `http://localhost:4200/assets/bootstrap.css`

Can someone throw me a bone here ?

Thx

Edit :

```
ember -v
ember-cli 0.0.23
```

brocfile.js

```
    /* global require, module */

var uglifyJavaScript = require('broccoli-uglify-js');
var replace = require('broccoli-replace');
var compileES6 = require('broccoli-es6-concatenator');
var validateES6 = require('broccoli-es6-import-validate');
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');

var env = require('broccoli-env').getEnv();
var getEnvJSON = require('./config/environment');

var p = require('ember-cli/lib/preprocessors');
var preprocessCss = p.preprocessCss;
var preprocessTemplates = p.preprocessTemplates;
var preprocessJs = p.preprocessJs;

module.exports = function (broccoli) {

  var prefix = 'caisse';
  var rootURL = '/';

  // index.html

  var indexHTML = pickFiles('app', {
    srcDir: '/',
    files: ['index.html'],
    destDir: '/'
  });

  indexHTML = replace(indexHTML, {
    files: ['index.html'],
    patterns: [{ match: /\{\{ENV\}\}/g, replacement: getEnvJSON.bind(null, env)}]
  });

  // sourceTrees, appAndDependencies for CSS and JavaScript

  var app = pickFiles('app', {
    srcDir: '/',
    destDir: prefix
  });

  app = preprocessTemplates(app);

  var config = pickFiles('config', { // Don't pick anything, just watch config folder
    srcDir: '/',
    files: [],
    destDir: '/'
  });

  var sourceTrees = [app, config, 'vendor'].concat(broccoli.bowerTrees());
  var appAndDependencies = mergeTrees(sourceTrees, { overwrite: true });

  // JavaScript

  var legacyFilesToAppend = [
    'jquery.js',
    'handlebars.js',
    'ember.js',
    'ic-ajax/dist/named-amd/main.js',
    'ember-data.js',
    'ember-resolver.js',
    'ember-shim.js',
    'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
  ];

  var applicationJs = preprocessJs(appAndDependencies, '/', prefix);

  applicationJs = compileES6(applicationJs, {
    loaderFile: 'loader/loader.js',
    ignoredModules: [
      'ember/resolver',
      'ic-ajax'
    ],
    inputFiles: [
      prefix + '/**/*.js'
    ],
    legacyFilesToAppend: legacyFilesToAppend,
    wrapInEval: env !== 'production',
    outputFile: '/assets/app.js'
  });

  if (env === 'production') {
    applicationJs = uglifyJavaScript(applicationJs, {
      mangle: false,
      compress: false
    });
  }

  // Styles

  var styles = preprocessCss(appAndDependencies, prefix + '/styles', '/assets');

  // Bootstrap Style integration
  var bootstrap = pickFiles('vendor', {
    srcDir: '/bootstrap/dist/css',
    files: [
      'bootstrap.css',
      'bootstrap-theme.css'
    ],
    destDir: '/assets/'
  });

//var bootstrap = preprocessCss(appAndDependencies, '/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css', '/assets');

  // Ouput

  var outputTrees = [
    indexHTML,
    applicationJs,
    'public',
    styles,
    bootstrap
  ];

  // Testing

  if (env !== 'production') {

    var tests = pickFiles('tests', {
      srcDir: '/',
      destDir: prefix + '/tests'
    });

    var testsIndexHTML = pickFiles('tests', {
      srcDir: '/',
      files: ['index.html'],
      destDir: '/tests'
    });

    var qunitStyles = pickFiles('vendor', {
      srcDir: '/qunit/qunit',
      files: ['qunit.css'],
      destDir: '/assets/'
    });

    testsIndexHTML = replace(testsIndexHTML, {
      files: ['tests/index.html'],
      patterns: [{ match: /\{\{ENV\}\}/g, replacement: getEnvJSON.bind(null, env)}]
    });

    tests = preprocessTemplates(tests);

    sourceTrees = [tests, 'vendor'].concat(broccoli.bowerTrees());
    appAndDependencies = mergeTrees(sourceTrees, { overwrite: true });

    var testsJs = preprocessJs(appAndDependencies, '/', prefix);

    var validatedJs = validateES6(mergeTrees([app, tests]), {
      whitelist: {
        'ember/resolver': ['default'],
        'ember-qunit': [
          'globalize',
          'moduleFor',
          'moduleForComponent',
          'moduleForModel',
          'test',
          'setResolver'
        ]
      }
    });

    var legacyTestFiles = [
      'qunit/qunit/qunit.js',
      'qunit-shim.js',
      'ember-qunit/dist/named-amd/main.js'
    ];

    legacyFilesToAppend = legacyFilesToAppend.concat(legacyTestFiles);

    testsJs = compileES6(testsJs, {
      // Temporary workaround for
      // https://github.com/joliss/broccoli-es6-concatenator/issues/9
      loaderFile: '_loader.js',
      ignoredModules: [
        'ember/resolver',
        'ember-qunit'
      ],
      inputFiles: [
        prefix + '/**/*.js'
      ],
      legacyFilesToAppend: legacyFilesToAppend,

      wrapInEval: true,
      outputFile: '/assets/tests.js'
    });

    var testsTrees = [qunitStyles, testsIndexHTML, validatedJs, testsJs];
    outputTrees = outputTrees.concat(testsTrees);
  }

  return mergeTrees(outputTrees, { overwrite: true });
};
```

Comment: Can you show your ember-cli version and Brocfile.js content?

Comment: Also including via the index.html after copying in /styles worked. <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-theme.css">

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You might want to check out [ember-bootstrap](http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/), which will import the bootstrap assets automatically.

```
ember install ember-bootstrap
```

Moreover it adds a suite of native ember components to your app, that make working with bootstrap features much easier in ember. Check it out, although I am a bit biased, as I am the author of it! ;)

Comment: This command is enough to transform any existing ember project to bootstrap. Thank you Simon.

Comment: ember-bootstrap is EXCELLENT! However a missing component from this is the carousel. If you need the carousel to work then you will need to install the bootstrap components via @rastapasta instructions -- it appears that ember-bootstrap does not include the transitions.js as a part of the bootstrap assets that it brings in, and this is REQUIRED for the carousel.

Comment: @RyanNerd Thanks! Yes, carousel still missing. But should be added hopefully some time soon after upcoming 1.0 release!

Answer (score 68):

BASH:

```
bower install --save bootstrap
```

Brocfile.js:

```
app.import('vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
app.import('vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

The JS will be added to the app.js, which is linked by default, and the CSS will be added to `assets/vendor.css`, which as of May 14th, is also added by default.

For reference: http://www.ember-cli.com/#managing-dependencies

In response to @Joe's question surrounding fonts and other assets, I was unable to get the recommended app.import() method to work on the fonts.  I instead opted for the merge-trees and static-compiler approach:

```
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');
var extraAssets = pickFiles('vendor/bootstrap/dist/fonts',{
    srcDir: '/', 
    files: ['**/*'],
    destDir: '/fonts'
});

module.exports = mergeTrees([app.toTree(), extraAssets]);
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! Forgot the cli doesn't render vendor.css initially.

Comment: Does this handle the files that LESS includes, like the fonts?

Comment: And restart the server since changes to the brocfile won't be automatically picked up by Livereload... I think :)

Comment: If you are using ember-cli v0.0.35 or newer you may need to include a couple of Broccoli plugins in your package.json. You can add them via: `npm install --save-dev broccoli-merge-trees` and `npm install --save-dev broccoli-static-compiler`.

Comment: Note that now 'vendor' has been replaced by 'bower_components' for anything installed with bower.  The 'vendor' folder can still be used for user-specified libraries.

Comment: You can also import fonts with ```app.import('vendor/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff', {
  destDir: 'fonts'
});``` Check the following link http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2014/08/10/import-bootstrap-glyphicons-in-ember-cli/

Comment: It seems my generated project requested boostrap.css.map as well, so I added the line of code below as well.

`app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map', { destDir: 'assets' });`

Comment: brocfile.js is no more; now, it's more like `ember-cli-build.js` that you have to add the `app.import` statements to.

Answer (score 46):

**BASH:**

```
bower install --save bootstrap
```

**Brocfile.js:**

```
/* global require, module */

...


app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map', {
    destDir: 'assets'
});
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
});
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
});
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
});
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
});
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
});

app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

Comment: This is a good method for ember 1.9 until ember-cli-bootstrap is bumped to build for handlebars >=2.0

Comment: The commands that Sean O'Hara stated in a comment on Drew's answer should be added to this: `npm install --save-dev broccoli-merge-trees && npm install --save-dev broccoli-static-compiler`

Comment: @TimoLehto what advantage does cli give over this broc import?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper, sry mate. I do not understand the question. What cli? What are you talking about?

Comment: @genkilabs dont see the point of the cli-bootstrap, its easy as shown above

Comment: @TimoLehto please see my commnet

Comment: Who's saying anything about cli-bootsrap? Not me. I am confused. I only said you need to also install broccoli-merge-trees broccoli-static-compiler to make this work. Nothing about cli-bootsrap.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper The reason for using cli-bootstrap (IMO) is because not only does it keep the bootstrap install in-line with other cli add-ons, but it is more clear and repeatable for large teams building several apps to a standard or hiring on and training new developers. Of course it doesn't matter for small teams or toy apps, but using consistent practices, installs and addons can help reduce error for industrial development.

Comment: @TimoLehto The original question here is about install in the Ember-CLI environment; its in the title.

Comment: @genkilabs thanks but, I'm still not convinced, its pretty easy for teams with bootstrap in bower and a merge trees in the brocfile whats going on, + you can easily change the bootstrap version.

Answer (score 23):

### Update 3/30/15

plus ça change... I use [ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy](https://github.com/lifegadget/ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy) now, it seems to bring along minimum cruft while still letting me customize Bootstrap's variables.

---

#### Update 1/22/15

You should probably use Johnny's solution above instead of the lib I originally mentioned. I also like [ember-cli-bootstrap-sass](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-cli-bootstrap-sass), because I can customize Bootstrap's variables directly in my project.

#### Original 7/11/14

If you're using a version of ember-cli that supports addons (0.35+, I believe), you can now use the [ember-cli-bootstrap](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-cli-bootstrap) package. From the root of your app,

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-bootstrap
```

That's it!

> Note: as @poweratom points out, `ember-cli-bootstrap` is somebody else's library which chooses to also include [bootstrap-for-ember](https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember). Thus, this lib could get out of sync with official bootstrap version. However, I still find it a great way to get prototyping fast on a new project!

Comment: Change current to your current version. Current today (0.0.39) is maybe not even the version you are using...

Comment: For right now ember-cli-bootstrap does not include bootstrap.js, so you want be able to utilize built-in javascript methods, or the various plugins.

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be a "recommended" way to install it per se. 'The ember-cli-bootstrap' project relies on the 'bootstrap-for-ember' project. Unfortunately, according to the maintainer of the latter project, he announced that he's now working on the 'ember-components' project as its successor instead. So unless there are efforts to pick up where he left off (that project is currently using bootstrap 3.0.0 I believe), the Bootstrap version will get stale soon enough (already is).

Answer (score 15):

```
$> bower install --save bootstrap
```

Afterwards add following two lines to your *ember-cli-builds.js* (or *Brocfile.js* if you are using an older version of Ember.js):

```
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

And voilà, ready to go!

***updated 08/18/2015:** adapted to new scheme introduced in Ember.js 1.13*

Comment: Latest version of ember-cli does not include brocfile.js anymore

Comment: @MadScientist , you can use the 'ember-cli-build.js' for importing, steps above still work. (ember: 1.12.6)

Comment: how do you combine this approach with bootstrap overrides like https://bootswatch.com/flatly/

Answer (score 6):

If you're using SASS (probably via `ember-cli-sass`), `bower_components` is automatically added to the lookup path. This means you can just use Bower and avoid the Brocfile/ember-cli-build file altogether.

Install the official SASS version of Bootstrap with Bower

```
bower install --save bootstrap-sass
```

then import the lib in `app.scss`. The nice thing about this is you can customize the variables before importing bootstrap:

```
$brand-primary: 'purple';

@import 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
```

Comment: or $ ember install ember-cli-sass
    $ ember install ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy
 then rename app.css to app.scss and add this line to it: @import "bootstrap"

Answer (score 5):

This is how I package vendor CSS files with Broccoli (which underpins Ember-cli).

```
 var vendorCss = concat('vendor', {
   inputFiles: [
     'pikaday/css/pikaday.css'
   , 'nvd3/nv.d3.css'
   , 'semantic-ui/build/packaged/css/semantic.css'
   ]
  , outputFile: '/assets/css/vendor.css'
  });
```

Where the `vendor` folder is where my Bower packages live. And `assets` is where I'm expecting my CSS to live. I'm assuming you've installed Bootstrap using Bower, which is the Ember-cli way.

Then in my index.html, I'm simply referencing that `vendor.css` file:

```
  <link href="/assets/css/vendor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Cheers.

Comment: I tried it but it tels me that concat is undefined in Broccoli (ReferenceError: concat is not defined) I added that with just changing the path to included stylesheets in the file : Brocfile.js at the root of the app folder.

Comment: Install the plugin `npm install broccoli-concat --save`
Then in your Brocfile, at the top: `var concat = require('broccoli-concat');`

Answer (score 3):

```
bower install --save bootstrap
```

in your `brocfile.js`:

```
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

Comment: I don't know why this was actually marked down. It may not be very clear unless you know where to put these statements. But it works fine... maybe not as nice as the add-on I admit.

they go in the `ember-cli-build.js` file and works fine if anyone needs this. I'm feeding my ember from within as Asp.Net MVC project and needed it available to that project not just the ember app.

Answer (score 0):

On the terminal (For those using Node Package Manager)

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Using ember-cli, to import your installed bootstrap

Open the `ember-cli-build.js` file

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
  });
app.import('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
app.import('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
```

That will do it if bootstrap is installed via the NPM installer.

Do not do this:

```
app.import('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
app.import('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
```