# Recommended way to use Bootstrap's LESS source in Ember.JS ember-cli app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, build, less, ember-cli

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349959/recommended-way-to-include-bootstrap-library-in-ember-js-ember-cli-app), it looks like linking to Bootstrap's `dist` files is easy.

However, I'm using LESS in my project and want to take advantage of Bootstrap's LESS files. What's the recommended way to link this all up?

Also, since using LESS is technically using Bootstrap's *source files*, should I also link to Bootstrap's JS source too? Or is it fine to assume mixing sources `bootstrap/less` and compiled dists `bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js` will just work?

Answer (score 10):

As of Ember CLI version 0.1.1, this is the recommended way to use Bootstrap's less in your project.

First, install bootstrap:

```
$ bower install --save-dev bootstrap
```

Then install the less preprocessor

```
$ npm install --save-dev ember-cli-less
```

Then replace app.css with app.less in this folder:

```
/app/styles/
```

Inside your new app.less file, add this to the top of the file:

```
@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
```

In your Brocfile.js, add this:

```
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
```

If you also want to use glyphicons that are bundled with boostrap, add this to Brocfile.js (`ember-cli-build.js` if you're using the latest `ember-cli`):

```
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
});
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
});
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
});
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps I did:

1. Ensure ember-cli compiles your `.less` files by installing `broccoli-less-single`

   ```
   $ npm install --save-dev ember-cli-less
   ```
2. Install bootstrap3 with `bower`

   ```
   $ bower install bootstrap --save
   ```
3. Remove `app/styles/app.css` and create your own `app/styles/app.less`

   ```
   @import "vendor/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
   ```

BONUS:
You can import bootstrap.js through the `Brocfile.js` file. Just add

```
app.import('vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
```

NOTE: In your `app/index.html`, make sure you add

```
<script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Ember 2.8 solution from `ember-cli-less` addon readme worked for me:

Install Bootstrap source:

```
bower install --S bootstrap
```

Specify the include paths in `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  lessOptions: {
    paths: [
      'bower_components/bootstrap/less'
    ]
   }
});
```

Import into app.less:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

Taken from: https://github.com/gdub22/ember-cli-less#examples

Answer (score 0):

You may have found solution for this already, but with ember-cli 0.0.33+, bower install -S bootstrap, which saves your files to the vendor folder and writes to your bower.json file.

Follow that up with `app.import('vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');` in your Brocfile.js. I included an app.less file in `app/styles/. You can reference your`vendor/bootstrap/less/` from there.

I also include a custom.less import at the bottom of my app.less where I can write my own stuff.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Less version of Bootstrap with *ember-cli*:

1. install Bootstrap Bower package

   ```
   $ bower install --save bootstrap
   ```
2. import `bootstrap.less` into `app/styles/app.less`

   ```
   @import "vendor/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
   ```