# Where do 3rd party JS libraries go?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-pods

In an Ember CLI app. If one wanted to use https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tooltip.js

http://www.ember-cli.com/ does not seem to mention anything specific about this.

Where would this file typically be stored? At first glance, I was thinking of putting it in `public/assets/js`. What is the convention, if any?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349959/recommended-way-to-include-bootstrap-library-in-ember-js-ember-cli-app or use an addon https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-bootstrap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is a convention. Use `bower` if a package exists. If it doesn't, download the repo into the `vendor` folder. Import the file in your `Brocfile.js`

```
app.import('vendor/path_to/main_js_file.js');
```

Comment: So they go in `vendor/` and not `public/`? Don't assets in `public/assets` get compiled to `vendor` anyways? On that thought, would it be fine storing them directly in `public`?

Comment: Go to http://www.ember-cli.com/, scroll to folder Layout, and peep this line: `vendor/ Your external dependencies not installed with Bower or Npm.` Also, `vendor.js` is different from this folder.

Comment: Oh sweet. Must have missed that!

Comment: You say use bower if package exists, but most plugin developers also provide npm packages. So what is the way to install/consume npm packages ?

Comment: @testndtv `npm install` in a `ember-cli` app from proj base directory will put the packages into the `node_modules` directory by default. If the package is an ember addon, it will automatically be imported into the app. If it isn't, use the same `app.import`. But most npm packages I've ever used are server side utils, and bower generally has the client side libraries. Obvs not always the case but in 20+ external libs in my current proj, not one client side is installed via bower except the Ember addons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use bower or place them in `vendor/`. Then register them in `ember-cli-build.js`

Here's the documentation: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/