# Adding WrapBootstrap Theme to Ember (2.0)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've installed ember-cli-less and I have included

```
@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap"
```

In the my styles/app.less file

I have the following in ember-cli-build.js file:

```
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
  });
  app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
  });
  app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
  });
  app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
  });
  app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
  });

  app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');

  return app.toTree();
```

Now I want to take a theme from Wrapbootstrap and include it in my project.

There is another link to a similiar question: [Recommended way to include bootstrap library in Ember.JS ember-cli App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349959/recommended-way-to-include-bootstrap-library-in-ember-js-ember-cli-app)  however - it seems to concentrate mostly on just getting bootstrap setup - it doesn't go much into adding a theme.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge (and I could be wrong here), since you're including bootstrap in app/style.css that will end up in your "app.css" file (instead of the vendor.css file).

In that situation I think you also have to import your theme from your app/styles.less.

```
@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap"
@import "path/to/wrap-boostrap/theme/main.css|.less file"
```

I assume you can leave the extension out for a css file in less, it's just to point out that you want the path to the css/less file of the theme.

One thing to remember is that `vendor.css` is placed before `app.css` (in the html page) which means that any other plugins the are counting on bootstrap.css being available will not work if you do `app.import('path/to/jquery/plugin.css)` you will have to include them in you app.less file as well.