# bootstrap@4.0.0-beta install issue for the Ember js

Tags: ember.js, bootstrap-4

Im try to install`bootstrap@4.0.0-beta` for the Ember js application im  used following method  `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta`,but its not work for my projects,
anyone know how to install correctly Ember js for the bootstrap@4.0.0-beta

Boostrap 4 beta>  http://getbootstrap.com/

Thanks

Comment: sir im try it, not work

Comment: try this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23634931/5771666 . use bower for installing bootstrap